# Trouble getting tree height scala code to run

Tags: scala, recursion, tree

I'm trying to create a tree object and find the height of a TreeNode but I'm having trouble figuring out how to run the code.

```scala
class Tree[A] {
    class TreeNode(var _value: A, var _left: TreeNode,
                       var _right: TreeNode)
    def height(root: TreeNode) = {
      def helper(curr: TreeNode, d: Int): Int = {
        if (root == null) d
        else {
          val leftDepth = helper(curr._left,d+1)
          val rightDepth = helper(curr._right,d+1)
          leftDepth max rightDepth
        }
      }
      helper(root,-1)
    }
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    var a: Tree[Int] = new Tree()
    a.height(10)

  }
```

I'm getting the error:

> Type mismatch, Required: Tree[Int]#TreeNode
> Found: Int

and I'm not sure how to create a `TreeNode` that can be passed to height along with the helper to calculate the height

Comment: `height` expects a **Tree** and you are passing an **Int**, how did you expect this to work? What is the idea that you have in your mind but are struggling to put on code.

Comment: Yes, because it's not letting me create a TreeNode. At least, I don't know how to

Comment: Probably something `val tree = new a.TreeNode(_value = 0, _left = null, _right = null)`  - But as I said on **Gitter** your code is far from being idiomatic and feels weird; take a look to [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/upmzeR5CRfK7pJqWPPzacQ/4) for an idiomatic solution.

Comment: yea that's similar to how I was thinking to do it. It's giving me cannot resolve symbol error's... thanks for the link

Comment: [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/bu4tvs56ThKABbruAOpm4Q/1) seems to compile as I suggested, it doesn't work due to a **NPE** _(one of the many reasons to avoid `null`)_.

Comment: yea it's working now besides the exception. Thanks